# Multiplexing 3 phase motor driver signals to drive a BLDC motor bidirectionally

Tags: switches, brushless-dc-motor, cmos, multiplexer, motor-controller

[I have this unidirectional 3 phase motor driver](https://www.mikroe.com/brushless-4-click) powered by a 3S LiPo battery and want to make it be able to switch direction of the brushless motor connected to it within software. The way to reverse the direction of rotation of the brushless motor is by switching two of the wires with each other. I've found that multiplexers or CMOS switches can help with this. Would my following setup be able to do this signal switching?

Ao/Co are motor driver outputs (PWM, max 1.5A output) and Ai/Ci are inputs to the bldc motor itself. L1 and L2 are the logic inputs to the multiplexer or CMOS switch.

[image: Circuit setup]

Comment: Use a relay not multiplexers.

Comment: @Andyaka Why would that be and how would it work? Would the mechanical nature not slow down the switching? There also appears to be an abundance of CMOS switches and multiplexers vs no 3.3v logic relays around. (I am based in Australia)

Comment: Do some digging and ask "how much current can a multiplexer supply to a load".